# Jupyter Notebook kernel dies when it tries to invoke elasticsearch

Tags: python, docker, elasticsearch, jupyter-notebook, allennlp

I'm getting a recurrent problem on my Jupyter Notebook. It runs a NLP model training with no issues, but after invoking elasticsearch to visualize some data on a dedicated UI, with these command

```
pl_trained.explore(valid_ds, explain=True)
```

andthese output:

```
INFO:biome.text.ui.ui:Running biome UI on http://0.0.0.0:8080 with elasticsearch backend http://localhost:9200
```

The notebook sends the message that the kernel has died and it will restart automatically. Elasticsearch is being runned with a docker instance, and in the localhost 9200 everything seems to be right:

```
    {
  "name" : "f72a33c77fca",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "Qac32YLsRe2Kbuqx72-aOQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.7.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "ad56dce891c901a492bb1ee393f12dfff473a423",
    "build_date" : "2020-05-28T16:30:01.040088Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.5.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

But localhost 8080 cannot be reached. Any ideas? I'm kinda new to docker, so I don't know if the problem is there or in other part of the code. The package I'm using, biome text, runs over AllenNLP, which is built on top of Pytorch.